# Minor bug on lists entered and displayed

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

Sorry if I got it wrong.
Was trying to add some points to the question in GIS SE page and found this one.Tried this in here and it is the same.Please see the screenshot attached.

[image]

As the text entry field displayed list wrongly the numbering .Its showing correctly in the Preview pane and the uploaded question.Dont know if it is bug or not.
[May be the answer is exactly how to start a new list in entry pane..]

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137077/cant-start-a-numbered-list-on-a-number-other-than-1/137078#137078 (specifically, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137085/163863).

Answer (score 4):

That's how markdown works.

By adding the bold text, the list numbering resets.

If you want to keep the numbering going on, you need to make the bold text **part** of the list, by indenting it:

```
1. Item

    **bold text**

2. Another Item
```

Produces:

1. Item

   **bold text**
2. Another Item